Deploy multipe Django, Celery & Redis App in one VPS
I am planning to deploy multiple applications(approx 100+) in single VPS.
Each Django app will have it's own celery and redis app.
How should I deploy all these applications properly?
I have tried to create individual service for each application but it became impossible to create a new service each time I'm deploying a new application.

Please elaborate your requirements. Are you trying to deploy it via k8s or docker.? Please provide more information

Thanks for asking.
I am deploying it without docker or k8s. My idea is to deploy 100 different application in the same server. Each project will be deployed from different user account(same VPS). After uploading the project, I will configure it using apache server.
What is the best way to do it?
